# JavaScript Exception: JavaScript Error: arguments[0].click is not a function when trying to click on hidden elements Selenium WebDriver JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to click on the select tag which is a hidden element, and getting the error:  JavascriptError: javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function

My HTML Code is:

```
<div class="form-group field-postform-expiration">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="postform-expiration">Paste Expiration:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9 field-wrapper">
   **<select id="postform-expiration" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" name="PostForm[expiration]" data-s2-options="s2options_7ebc6538" data-krajee-select2="select2_a09a7382" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; visibility: hidden;" data-select2-id="postform-expiration" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">**
    <option value="N" data-select2-id="4">Never</option>
    <option value="B">Burn after read</option>
    <option value="10M">10 Minutes</option>
    <option value="1H">1 Hour</option>
    <option value="1D">1 Day</option>
    <option value="1W">1 Week</option>
    <option value="2W">2 Weeks</option>
    <option value="1M">1 Month</option>
    <option value="6M">6 Months</option>
    <option value="1Y">1 Year</option>
  </select>
  <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="3" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="selection">
      <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-postform-expiration-container">
        <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-postform-expiration-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Never">Never</span>
        <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
          <b role="presentation"></b>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript code to automate the click in selenium webDriver is:

```
async selectValueFromDropdown(locator) {
    await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", locator)
  }
```

Note that I'm using Javascript to automate the scripts, not Java.
I tried to search from google and still getting the error Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: Seems like you'd need a "webelement" type there not a locator.

Comment: @pcalkins locator is used to locating the element that is needs to be clicked. In other words, locator is                           let selectButton = "#postform-expiration"
    await this.selectValueFromDropdown(selectButton)